# my whole rails app is getting css only from one file why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass

I had added different css files for both the controllers but my whole app is only taking css from the `product.css`

I had added different css files for both the controllers but my whole app is only taking css from the `product.css`
I had added different css files for both the controllers but my whole app is only taking css from the `product.css`

**products.css**

```
body {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #4A4A4A ;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrap {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 380px;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px 
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px 
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 29px;
}

.wrap img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

p{ 
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: justify;
}

h1{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 5px; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4A4A4A !important;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #6B6B6B !important ;
}
```

**

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice. Instead edit your question adding some more details - it will move up in the list. Please show your other css file in this question as well as your application.css file. How do you know that products.css is the only file that is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay you're using SCSS mixed with CSS, my advice would be to change product.css into product.scss and import the paths using

```
 @import '/*';
 @import '/**/*';
```

Depending on your folder structure else rails will throw an error if it can't find any files because rails is not picking up the scss files.

Also you could remove all the asset pipeline stuff and do @import 'font-awesome';

Comment: What does your folder structure looks like? And the file extensions.

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by folder structure @Chong Hui